# Page respective controller will load on demand in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html

I am new in angularjs.I am making an SPA appliaction in angularjs with HTML5.I would like to load page related controller when tempalate page called. for Example I have three html page Index.html, HOME.Html and contact.html and have respective controller homecontroller.js and contactController.js. HOME.Html and contact.html is load on demand in ng-view section of Index.html.

When i add reference of homecontroller.js and contactController.js on index.html then it work fine but i would like to load respective controller of HOME.Html and contact.html on demand means when home is called then only homecontroller.js will be load and when contactis called then only contactController.js will be load.

Any one please suggest how it will achieve this

Comment: can you please show some code?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the UI-Router :

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
      controller: 'homeController',
      controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .state('contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      templateUrl: "partials/contact.html",
      controller: 'contactController',
      controllerAs: 'contactCtrl'
    })    ;
});
```